# Adjusting output in fviz_cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I would like to change the results of my `fviz_clust` plot. Specifically, change the legend to say "Cluster" instead of "cluster", but also remove the curly lines found within the legend (I think they are letters, but not entirely sure).

I know `fviz_cluster` works with other elements in `ggplot.` Therefore my first thought was to change the legend title within each `scale_..._..` of my plot, but that still resulted in the original legend displaying. Secondly, I thought I could introduce a `scale_shape_manual()` object to `ggplot` but the plot ignored it.

Code:

```
km.res <- kmeans(iris[,-5], 3)
p <- fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[,-5]) +
scale_color_brewer(palette='Set2') + # set guides=FALSE to remove legend
scale_fill_brewer(palette='Set2') +
scale_shape_manual('1'=22,'2'=23,'3'=24) # plot ignores this
ggtitle(label='')
p
```

Ideally I would like to show a very similar legend to what fviz_cluster produces, but with the shape and box of color around each shape in the legend. And finally with the title of "Cluster."

Comment: Hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). But running the Iris example from `fviz_cluster` I'm able to change these things the same as any other `ggplot`. Your question doesn't include what you've done to try changing the legend or shape

Comment: Sorry about not using iris. But my question does include what I've done to change the legend and shape.

Comment: You can remove legends with `theme(legend.position = "none")`. Take a look at the docs for setting manual scales, such as shape: you supply 1 vector to the argument `values`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fviz_cluster` works with `ggplot`, you had an error in the code that caused changes to not be rendered properly.

With regards to changing the title to "Cluster", you can do this within `scales-..._...` or `guides`. Specify the new shape values in `scale_shape_manual`.

```
library(factoextra)
km.res <- kmeans(iris[, -5], 3)

p <- fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5]) +
  scale_color_brewer('Cluster', palette='Set2') + 
  scale_fill_brewer('Cluster', palette='Set2') +
  scale_shape_manual('Cluster', values=c(22,23,24)) + 
  ggtitle(label='') 
p
```

[image]

Removing the text label annotation in the legend can usually be done by specifying `geom_text(show.legend = F)`. I could not do this directly so instead I plot only the points in `fviz_cluster`, and then add the `geom_text` after by making use of the data structure produced by `fviz_cluster`.

```
p2 <- fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], geom = c("point")) +
  scale_color_brewer('Cluster', palette='Set2') + 
  scale_fill_brewer('Cluster', palette='Set2') +
  scale_shape_manual('Cluster', values=c(22,23,24)) + 
  ggtitle(label='') 
p2 + geom_text(data=p2$data, aes(x=x, y=y, label=name, colour=cluster),
  vjust=-1, show.legend = F)
```

[image]